# Put Space Between TDs

Tags: html

I want to make space between my tags:

```
    <td style="text-align:left;">
    <strong><font size="7" color="white">Test</font></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
    <img src="example.png" alt="Banner" style="border:0;width:560px;height:95" />
    </td>
```

I tried doing this:

```
    <td style="text-align:left;">
    <strong><font size="7" color="white">Test</font></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="width:100;">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
    <img src="example.png" alt="Banner" style="border:0;width:560px;height:95" />
    </td>
```

Yet it seemed redundant, and it still didn't work! I just want to put 100 pixels between my first td and my last one, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: You are using `100` in the case that doesn't work, and `560px` in the case that (presumably) *does* work. Notice a pattern? :)

Comment: Side note: don't use <font> tag, it's been deprecated since the late '90s.  Use a <span> with `style` if you need to have inline styles, but really you should stick the styling in a <style>.

Comment: The thing is I'm not completely sure how a <span> tag works. This isn't the first time I've been told this, I'm just not completely sure why I shouldn't use the <font> tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put this in your stylesheet. Inline CSS can get very redundant and is not recomended.

```
table.padded tr td {
   padding-left: 100px;
}

table.padded tr td:first-child {
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

Then add the class `padded` (or something else if you wish) to your table.

Comment: Are you sure that it would still stay in the center of the page? That is important for my page layout

Comment: Yes it would. This just sets the padding inside the cells. You could also use margin if you want.

Comment: Try updating your table: `<table style="margin: 0 auto">`.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with your code. What is the table.class td:first-child mean? I'm specifically referring to your td:first-child part

Comment: `:first-child` is a CSS selector that means to select just the first `td` instead of all of them. Without that, all the `td`s would have a 100px left padding and this would lead to the table looking uneven on the first `td`. To add a class to an element, you just use that class attribute, in your case: `<table class="padded">`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `cellspacing`

```
 <table cellspacing='2'>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​​​​​​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/GWtf5/)

Comment: Wait nevermind about my last comment. This works perfectly. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I've seen where IE doesn't render a table cell if it is empty. Try putting a non-breaking space in it.  Having said that, CSS is definitely the way to go.

Comment: But then how would I use the CSS? I tried the answer that said to use padding, but it didn't work in my HTML document.

Comment: The padded class may have thrown you off? If you aren't familiar with using CSS in an HTML doc then you'll want to look up a tutorial, it's really worth it.